# How to get the variable name based on the received values?

Tags: c++, regex, macros

I have an MFC project. Each button, list control etc has its unique ID, like

```
#define IDC_LOGIN_BUTTON 1
#define IDC_EDIT_USERNAME 2
```

There are hundreds of items on the UI.
I can use hooker function to receive the windows message comes from user's button click. But how could I know which item triggers this message ?
For example(pesudo code):

```
#define PRINTAPI(x) std::cout << #x << std::endl;

int nRet = receiveWindowsNotificationCode();
switch(nRet):
{
 case IDC_LOGIN_BUTTON :
     PRINTAPI(IDC_LOGIN_BUTTON );
     break;
case IDC_EDIT_USERNAME :
     PRINTAPI(IDC_EDIT_USERNAME );
     break;
 .....

 }
```

Since I have hundreds of items on this UI, if I use switch case, it will be very long. Any better solutions ?

Comment: Control do not have to have unique ids.  When creating a dialog you can reuse IDs (as long as they are unique within the dialog).  You can see examples of this with the [OK] and [Cancel] buttons on many dialogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple solution.

But there is an almost simple solution:

You write a small tool that takes as input a file containing the list of all IDs:

```
IDC_LOGIN_BUTTON
IDC_EDIT_USERNAME
...
```

That tool would read that file and generate the corresponding C++ source code, in a file say cases_auto.inc, for example:

```
// automatically generated code
case IDC_LOGIN_BUTTON :
     PRINTAPI(IDC_LOGIN_BUTTON );
     break;
case IDC_EDIT_USERNAME :
     PRINTAPI(IDC_EDIT_USERNAME );
     break;
...
```

Then instead of writing:

```
int nRet = receiveWindowsNotificationCode();
switch(nRet):
{
 case IDC_LOGIN_BUTTON :
     PRINTAPI(IDC_LOGIN_BUTTON );
     break;
case IDC_EDIT_USERNAME :
     PRINTAPI(IDC_EDIT_USERNAME );
     break;
 .....

 }
```

you write:

```
int nRet = receiveWindowsNotificationCode();
switch(nRet):
{
   #include "cases_auto.inc"     
}
```

Slightly harder:

Your tool could parse directly the .h file containing the `#define IDC_...`

```
#define IDC_LOGIN_BUTTON 1
#define IDC_EDIT_USERNAME 2
```

The tool should take less than 20 lines of C code. You could also use a scripting language instead of C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what do you mean by "which item triggers this message".

If you want to text of the item(button/checkbox ...). All you need to do is

```
int nRet = receiveWindowsNotificationCode();


CWnd* itemWnd = GetDlgItem(nRet);
CString itemName;
if (itemWnd != NULL)
{
    GetWindowsText(itemWnd, itemName);
}
```

Now you have your button's text.

If you want the ID of the "item", one easy way is to parse the resource.h and map the ID with its string name.

But if you have this requirement of getting IDs, names and other properties in your mind before designing you project, the best solution is to create a base class of your controls, which you can retrieve id, text and other property easily. You can also apply consistent look and feel for these controls. For example, for all button type (real button, radio button...) use CMyBaseButton, which can GetID(), GetText(), GetStyle()... There is a little more work but it definitely worth it.

Comment: Actually, I need to log the ID(number) into a txt file, then read these numbers from log file and translate these numbers into button's name.